# Oracle DISTINCT NUMERIC - NOT DISTINCT CLOB; ORA-00932

Tags: oracle, distinct, sqlplus, numeric

Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24184089/oracle-distinct-ora-00932?noredirect=1#comment37331062_24184089).

I am interested in selecting a `DISTINCT NUMERIC` from `EVENTLOG` that has an accompanying `CLOB` from `EVENT_INFO_DETAIL` that is not intended to be a `DISTINCT` selection.

In other words, I am interested in selecting a `DISTINCT EVENTID_NBR` because of the presence of multiple of the same number and to also see the `CLOB` associated with that `DISTINCT EVENTID_NBR`.  I am NOT trying to select a `DISTINCT CLOB` in any way.  How might I go about doing this?

For example, a result set could look like the following:

```
EVENID_NBR    INPUT_ARGS (BYTE SIZE)

143           4096
143           3284
143           2162
143           2222
143           1024
```

I would want only one `EVENTID_NBR` because I need a representative sample in my result set but I also need the `CLOB` selected along with that `DISTINCT EVENTID_NBR`.

Is there a way to select just the first `ROWID` of each `EVENTID_NBR` that also include the associated `CLOB`?

Should I select a `DISTINCT EVENTID_NBR` and then try to find the `CLOB` associated with the `EVENTID_NBR` I have chosen?

Answer (score 0):

This is typically done with a window function:

```
select evenid_nbr,
       input_args
from (
  select evenid_nbr,
         input_args,
         row_number() over (partition by evenid_nbr order by rowid) as rn
  from event_info_detail
) t
where rn = 1
```

By changing the `order by` part you can adjust which evenid_nbr gets returned.

Comment: Can you show me how I am integrating my existing query with your window function answer please?

Comment: @Mushy There is no "existing query" in your question.